# Identity Generation error with EF5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

In my DbContext, I have an override of the SaveChanges method to generate a Guid for entities to be added to the Database. This works fine except in the case of a shared primary key.

It generates different Id instead of one to be shared by the entities. Is there a way to check the type of Relationship?

```
  public override int SaveChanges()
  {
      foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added))
      {
          var t = entry.Entity.GetType();
          if (t.GetProperty("Id") == null)
              continue;

          var info = t.GetProperty("Id").GetCustomAttributes(typeof (DatabaseGeneratedAttribute), true).Cast<DatabaseGeneratedAttribute>();
          if (!info.Any() || info.Single().DatabaseGeneratedOption != DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
          {
              if (t.GetProperty("Id").PropertyType == typeof(Guid) && (Guid)t.GetProperty("Id").GetValue(entry.Entity, null) == Guid.Empty)
                  t.GetProperty("Id").SetValue(entry.Entity, Guid.NewGuid(), null);
          }
      }
      return base.SaveChanges();
  }
```